# If $||P(v)||\leq ||v||$ for all $v\in V$, then $P$ is the orthogonal projection from $V$ to $W$. ("Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Kazuo Matsuzaka)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, orthogonality, direct-sum

I am reading "Introduction to Linear Algebra" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.
The following exercise (Exercise 6 on p.353) is in this book:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$.
> Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$.
> Let $W^{'}$ be a subspace of $V$ such that $V=W\oplus W^{'}$.
> Let $P:V\to W$ be a projection on $W$ along $W^{'}$.
> Prove the following:
> If $||P(v)||\leq ||v||$ for all $v\in V$, then $P$ is the orthogonal projection from $V$ to $W$.

I solved this exercise.
I guess this exercise is not difficult, but my solution is very long.
I am not sure my solution is ok.
Please give me a right solution if my solution is wrong.
Please give me a better (more natural) solution even if my solution is ok.

> We need to prove that $W^{'}=W^{\bot}$.
> Assume that $W^{'}\neq W^{\bot}$.
> If $(W^{'})^{\bot}=W$, then $W^{'}=((W^{'})^{\bot})^{\bot}=W^{\bot}$.
> But $W^{'}\neq W^{\bot}$ by assumption.
> So, $(W^{'})^{\bot}\neq W$.

> $\dim (W^{'})^{\bot}=\dim V-\dim W^{'}$.
> $\dim W=\dim V-\dim W^{'}$.
> So, $\dim (W^{'})^{\bot}=\dim W$.

> So, $W \not\subset (W^{'})^{\bot}$.

> So, there exists $w$ such that $w\in W$ and $w\notin (W^{'})^{\bot}$.

> Let $P^{'}:V\to (W^{'})^{\bot}$ be the orthogonal projection from $V$ to $(W^{'})^{\bot}$.
> Since $w\in V$ and $V=(W^{'})^{\bot}\oplus ((W^{'})^{\bot})^{\bot}$, we can write $w=w_1+w_2$ ($w_1\in (W^{'})^{\bot}, w_2\in ((W^{'})^{\bot})^{\bot}$).
> Since $w\notin (W^{'})^{\bot}$, $w_2\neq 0$.
> $P^{'}(w)=w_1$ holds by the definition of $P^{'}$.
> Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $(W^{'})^{\bot}$.
> Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_r,v_{r+1},\dots,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$.
> Then,
> $w=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (v_i|w)v_i$,
> $w_1=\sum_{i=1}^{r} (v_i|w)v_i$,
> $w_2=\sum_{i=r+1}^{n} (v_i|w)v_i$.

> $||P^{'}(w)||^2=||w_1||^2=(w_1|w_1)=\sum_{i=1}^{r} |(v_i|w)|^2$.
> $||w||^2=(w|w)=\sum_{i=1}^{r} |(v_i|w)|^2+\sum_{i=r+1}^{n} |(v_i|w)|^2$.
> Since $w_2\neq 0$, $||P^{'}(w)||^2<||w||^2$.
> So, $||P^{'}(w)||=||w_1||<||w||$.

> Since $w=w_1+w_2$, $w_1=w+(-w_2)\in W\oplus W^{'}$.
> So, $P(w_1)=w$.
> So, $||w||=||P(w_1)||\leq ||w_1||$.

> This is a contradiction.
> So, $W^{'}=W^{\bot}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof: Projection is orthogonal if it is nonexpanding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911295/proof-projection-is-orthogonal-if-it-is-nonexpanding)